# Android program stopped Unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, listview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Hello I am new to Android programming and I am a bit rusty with Java too since I haven't done it in a while.
I am trying to use an example that I found online and when I try to run it with the emulator it said that my program has stopped and I have no idea why.

All that I modified was the main Java file

The code that I have is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ScottTestActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //Values to display
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone",                                         
    "Windows Mobile", "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

Could someone please help me?  and if possible point me in a good direction that explains Android programming?

Comment: could you show us you logcat errors ?

Comment: Could you give us your main.xml too? Does it contain a ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this where you took your sample :

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

anyway as Dawid Sajdak  refers, it looks that there is no listview tag in main.xml

you need to add this to res/layout/main.xml

<

```
ListView
  android:id="@+android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

A good place to get started is the Developer's Guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Android applications consist of a mixture of java files and xml files that describe how your activities are laid out and how the application fits together.  Depending on the modifications you made to the main Java file (for example, if you changed the class name), you may have broken the application because an xml file still points to the old class name.

I recommend reading the Developer's Guide to get your feet wet and see how all the pieces fit together.  If it still doesn't make sense after doing that, you should post the original file as well as your modifications so we have a better idea what's going on.

My best clairvoyant guess is that you changes the class name in code and not in the xml.